# gerrit-cherry-pick:fatal: 'origin' does not appear to be a git repository

Tags: git, gerrit

I am running into following error while trying to do a `gerrit-cherry-pick`,I did a `git remote -v` and can see the `origin` is pointing to `ssh://waccount@tech-gerrit.sd.company.com:29418/tech-ci.git` ,can anyone provide guidance on why am hitting this error?how to debug this further an fix it?

```
2018-08-09 21:13:15 change-merged   runCmd               169    INFO    : Running command git --git-dir=/gerrit_v2/hooks/tech_projects/tech-ci/.git --work-tree=/gerrit_v2/hooks/tech_projects/tech-ci remote -v
2018-08-09 21:13:15 change-merged   runCmd               173    INFO    :
origin  ssh://waccount@tech-gerrit.sd.company.com:29418/tech-ci.git (fetch)
origin  ssh://waccount@tech-gerrit.sd.company.com:29418/tech-ci.git (push)

2018-08-09 21:13:15 change-merged   runCmd2              180    INFO    : Running command /gerrit_v2/hooks/gerrit-cherry-pick origin 20633/2
2018-08-09 21:13:15 change-merged   runCmd2              187    INFO    : fatal: 'origin' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

Gerrit-cherry-pick:

```
usage() {
  echo >&2 "usage: $0 remote changeid..."
  echo >&2 "usage: $0 --continue"
  echo >&2 "usage: $0 --skip"
  echo >&2 "usage: $0 --abort"
  echo >&2 "usage: $0 [--close|--replace] remote"
  exit 1
}

die() {
  echo >&2 "fatal: $1"
  exit 1
}

GIT_DIR=$(git rev-parse --git-dir) || exit
CL="$GIT_DIR/GERRIT_CHANGES"
STATE="$GIT_DIR/rebase-gerrit"
TODO="$STATE/todo"

RESOLVEMSG="
When you have resolved this problem run \"$0 --continue\".
If you would prefer to skip this patch, run \"$0 --skip\".
"

pop_action() {
  sed -e 1d <"$TODO" >>"$TODO".new
  mv -f "$TODO".new "$TODO"
}

mark_done() {
  read commit changeid <"$TODO"
  changeid=$(get_changeid "$changeid")
  head_after=$(git rev-parse HEAD^0)
  head_before=$(cat "$STATE/head_before")
  if ! test $head_after = $head_before
  then
    echo $head_after >"$CL/$changeid"
  fi
  pop_action
}

do_next() {
  while test -s "$TODO"
  do
    read commit changeid <"$TODO"
    git rev-parse HEAD^0 >"$STATE/head_before"
    git format-patch \
        -k --stdout --full-index --ignore-if-in-upstream \
        $commit^..$commit |
    git am $git_am_opt --rebasing --resolvemsg="$RESOLVEMSG" || exit
    mark_done
  done

  echo >&2 "Done."
  rm -rf "$STATE"
}

git_am_opt=
if test -f "$STATE/git_am_opt"
then
  git_am_opt=$(cat "$STATE/git_am_opt")
fi

while test $# != 0
do
  case "$1" in
  --continue)
    test -f "$TODO" || die "No cherry-pick in progress?"
    git am $git_am_opt --rebasing --resolvemsg="$RESOLVEMSG" --resolved || exit
    mark_done
    do_next
    exit
    ;;
  --skip)
    test -f "$TODO" || die "No cherry-pick in progress?"
    git reset --hard HEAD || exit
    git am --skip || exit
    pop_action
    do_next
    exit
    ;;
  --abort)
    test -f "$TODO" || die "No cherry-pick in progress?"
    git reset --hard HEAD
    git am --skip
    rm -rf "$STATE"
    ;;
  --close|--replace)
    shift
    test -d "$CL" || die "No changes to close"
    test $# = 1   || usage
    remote=$1
    printf %s "git push $remote" >&2
    rs=$(cd "$CL" && for change_id in *; do
      test "$change_id" = '*' && die "No changes to close"
      c=$(cat "$change_id");
      echo "$c:refs/changes/$change_id";
      echo ' \' >&2;
      printf %s "  $c:refs/changes/$change_id" >&2
      done)
    echo >&2
    echo >&2
    git push $remote $rs
    rc=$?
    test $rc = 0 && rm -rf "$CL"
    exit $rc
    ;;
  --whitespace=*)
    git_am_opt="$git_am_opt $1"
    ;;
  --committer-date-is-author-date|--ignore-date)
    git_am_opt="$git_am_opt $1"
    ;;
  -C*)
    git_am_opt="$git_am_opt $1"
    ;;
  -s|--signoff)
    git_am_opt="$git_am_opt $1"
    ;;
  -*)
    usage
    ;;
  *)
    break
    ;;
  esac
  shift
done

get_changeid() {
  case $1 in
  */*) echo ${1%%/*} ;;
  *)   echo $1 ;;
  esac
}

to_ref() {
  case $1 in
  */*)
    change_id=${1%%/*}
    patchset_id=${1##*/}
    ;;
  *)
    change_id=$1
    patchset_id=1
    ;;
  esac

  hash=$(($change_id % 100))
  case $hash in
  [0-9]) hash="0$hash" ;;
  esac

  echo "refs/changes/$hash/$change_id/$patchset_id"
}

get_revid() {
  grep $(to_ref $1) <"$GIT_DIR/FETCH_HEAD" | cut -f1
}

# Initialize state
#
test $# -lt 2 && usage
remote="$1"
shift

mkdir "$STATE" || die "cherry-pick already in progress"
echo $git_am_opt >"$STATE/git_am_opt"

if ! git fetch $remote $(for id; do to_ref $id; done)
then
  rm -rf $STATE
  exit 1
fi

(for id
 do
  if revid=$(get_revid $id)
  then
    echo "$revid $id"
  else
    echo >&2 "fatal: $id not found"
    exit 1
  fi
done) >"$TODO"

mkdir -p "$CL"
echo >&2
do_next
```

Comment: Add to your question the contents of the /gerrit_v2/hooks/gerrit-cherry-pick file.

Comment: @MarceloÁviladeOliveira - I got the gerrit-cherry-pick from `https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/cmd-cherry-pick.html#_obtaining` ,I doubt it has anything to do with the gerrit-cherry-pick file

Answer (score 0):

That would indicate the user account making that command does not have its `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` default public SSH key registered in `~waccount/.ssh/authorized_keys` on the `tech-gerrit.sd.company.com` server.

If possible, try in that same command sequence, to execute

```
ssh -Tv -p 2941 waccount@tech-gerrit.sd.company.com
```

That will display more details on the failed connection attempt.

If not possible, try and make sure the environment variable `GIT_SSH_COMMAND` is set with '`ssh -v`'.

Comment: I ran the above command and got got the message `****    Welcome to Gerrit Code Review    ****^M
^M
  Hi waccount, you have successfully connected over SSH.^M` ,so it does look like it is registered,what else could be the issue,what can be tried? am running into the issue when running this command from a gerrit hook ,dont see when I run this outside of the hook

Comment: @Flair You need to make sure to run that command with the same user account as the one  actually running the hook.

Comment: @Flair If that is the case, then set the environment variable `GIT_SSH_COMMAND` to '`ssh -v`' and see if that generates more logs.

Comment: Like Marcello pointed out above , even though the current working directory is the repository clone the commands seems to be executed from the bare (gerrit)repository,I seem have the same problem while running any other git command aswell, any pointers on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're executing commands in the bare repository (the Gerrit repository) not in a work tree (the repository clone). Remember that hooks are executed inside the Gerrit repository which trigger them.

Comment: I explicitly change  the cwd to run from a worktree(the repository clone) but like you said even though the current working directory is the repository clone the commands seems to be executed from the bare repository,I seem have the same problem while running any other git command aswell, any idea why ?any pointers on how to debug this?really appreciate

Comment: How to change that?

Comment: I asked first :-)

Comment: I just used chdir to change the working directory ,when the `gerrit-cherry-pick` is being execued I print os.getcwd() and it is pointing to repository clone but somehow the commands run on gerrit repositories,not able to crack this?some environment setting ?any pointers?